# Writing $f(c)=2^{\lfloor \frac{c}{10} \rfloor}c$ without floor function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a way to write $f(c)=2^{\lfloor \frac{c}{10} \rfloor}c$ without using the floor function?

Comment: @JasperLoy $f(c) = 2^{\lfloor\frac{c}{10}\rfloor}c$

Comment: @JasperLoy It's a variable then. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for $f(c)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}2^kc\chi_{[10k,10(k+1))}(c)$ where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E$ that sends an element to $1$ if it is in $E$ and to $0$ otherwise.